# Laravel Has Many Through Eloquent Relationship not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Every row in "log" contains  key (dec_key), that used by users when they auth to the system
Table "Keys" contains keys (dec_key) and user ID (user)
Table "Users" contains user IDs (id) and they's logins (login)

I'm try' to create form with columns:

: log.id : keys.dec_key : keys.comment : users.login :

but something wrong in my code or database structure.

This is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE "log" (
"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, 
"dec_key" integer not null) 

CREATE TABLE "keys" (
"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, 
"dec_key" integer not null, 
"comment" varchar not null, 
"user" integer not null, foreign key("dec_key") references  "log"("dec_key") on delete cascade)

CREATE TABLE "users" (
"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, 
"login" varchar not null, 
foreign key("id") references "keys"("user") on delete cascade)
```

And my code

// LogsController.php

```
class LogsController extends Controller
{
public function index (Request $request) {
    $req = Log::with('comment:dec_key,comment','keyusers:*');
}
}
```

// log.php

```
class Log extends Model
{
protected $table = 'log';

public function comment () {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Key', 'dec_key', 'dec_key');
}

public function keyusers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Users', 'App\Key', 'user', 'id');
}
}
```

// Key.php

```
class Key extends Model
{
protected $table = 'keys';

public function userskeys()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Log','id','user');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Users','id','user');
}
}
```

// Users.php

```
class Users extends Model
{
protected $table = 'users';

public function keys () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Key', 'user', 'id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Log','user','id');
}
}
```

keyusers method returns an empty array.